# for loop error handling with specific error conditions (in R)

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, while-loop, try-catch

My problem is very similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999808/retry-for-loop-r-loop-if-error) but unfortunately I am unable to apply the code in the specific situation I am in.

So I am trying to download many URLs and I am using a for loop to get this done. This is how my loop might look like:

```
ids <- c("1", "3", "7", "9")

numbers <- list()
  for (jj in seq_along(ids)) {  
   numbers[[jj]] <- as.numeric(ids[jj])
      }
```

That works all dandy. Until I receive the Error `"Error: Try Again"`, which randomly appears but can be fixed if I just start the loop again at the same place.

However, there is a different error which signals that the API key I am using has expired `"Error: Stop for loop"`, and for this error I need to stop the loop, restart the API key manually (can't be automated unfortunately) and then start again at the iterator where it left off.

So to simulate this I wrote this little loop:

```
errors <- c("Error: Try Again", "Error: Stop for loop")

numbers <- list()
  for (jj in seq_along(ids)) {  
   numbers[[jj]] <- as.numeric(ids[jj])
    if (jj == sample(1:4, 1)) stop(sample(errors, 1)) 
   #randomly stops and gives one or the other error
  }
```

**So here is what I want to do:**

1. Whenever my for loop hits "Error: Try Again", I want the loop to try again until it works.
2. Whenever my for loop hits "Error: Stop for loop", I want the loop to stop so I can manually fix the API key error. In this case I want the results of the loop saved, so I can later rbind them together when I restart the loop.

Unfortunately, I am very unskilled in writing these kind of conditions. I know that I have to use `try` or `tryCatch` somehow but I am unable to figure out how I can test for specific error messages (rather than if an error occured at all).

Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: it's just an illustration because my actual loop code would have required the packages and I wanted an easy reproducible example that conveys the idea

Comment: That makes sense, after reading your question a little more carefully I figured that was the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is good. I pulled the error-generating part into its own function to make things more modular and easier to understand.

To easily "try things until success", a `while` loop makes more sense than a `for` loop. We can `break` to stop the loop. I've used `next` to jump to the next iteration of the loop, though it really isn't needed here (using it would skip everything left in the loop for the current iteration - but since there's really nothing that happens after my `next` statements they could be left out).

```
ids <- c("1", "3", "7", "9", "12", "13", "18")

foo = function() {
    errors <- c("Error: Try Again", "Error: Stop for loop")
    if (runif(1) < 0.25) stop(sample(errors, 1))
}

numbers <- list()
jj = 1
while(jj <= length(ids)) {
    numbers[[jj]] <- as.numeric(ids[jj])
  outcome = tryCatch(foo(), error = function(e) e)
  if (is.null(outcome)) {
    jj = jj + 1
    next
  } else if (outcome$message == "Error: Stop for loop") {
    message("Loop stopped on iteration ", jj)
    break
  } else if (outcome$message == "Error: Try Again"){
    next
  }
}
```